# Is returning an object that implements IDisposable a good idea or not?

Tags: .net, idisposable, dispose

My scenario is this.

I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement for dealing with AD users and groups. My Main method (this is a console app for now) calls into a method that returns `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>`. Both objects implement IDisposable.

If I return this, how can I ensure I can dispose of all these disposable objects?

```
class Searcher
{    
    private PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> SearchForObjects(string searchString)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = null;
        PrincipalSearcher principalSearcher = null;
        Principal principal = null;

        ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "blah", "dc=blah,dc=com");

        principal = new GroupPrincipal(ctx) { Name = searchString };
        principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher { QueryFilter = principal };

        return principalSearcher.FindAll();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Searchers searchers = new Searchers();

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> theGroups = searchers.SearchForGroupsMatching("some*");

    foreach (GroupPrincipal group in theGroups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.DisplayName);
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Is passing back the `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` a really bad idea, for reasons relating to unmanged object disposal?

Am I better off creating a managed proxy object?

I imagine that if I'm only caring about reading a subset of properties, it may be "better" to create a custom object containing only these properties. When writing back, in this case to an AD group, all I really need to pass into a method are the changed properties and the key. This would allow me to constrain the creation of unmanaged objects to one scope. Or is all of this unnecessary and more trouble than it's worth? My apologies for the semi-scattered stream of consciousness...

Comment: Note, any self-respecting `IDisposable` will dispose itself on finalization.  If you implement it correctly, there's no need for you to worry about whether the user disposes it or not -- at worst, they'll be tying up native resources for a little while longer than they have to.

Comment: I can only disagree with this. There is no guarantee that the finalizer will ever be called.

Comment: The finalizer will be called when an object is about to be GC'ed, unless the app exits before then.  Either way, the resources are released.

Comment: The managed resources are released when a .NET object falls out of scope. There is no guarantee that the associated unmanaged object will be cleaned up. I believe that it can exist (ahem) "forever".

Comment: @cHao: Please improve your understanding on this topic. It is not guaranteed that the finalizer of an object is run **ever**.

Comment: @Mike: Please improve your understanding on this topic. You don't even know what a finalizer is. ;-)

Comment: @Mike: Did you just post a comment to yourself? ;-)

Comment: @Daniel: It's not guaranteed *when* a finalizer runs, other than that it's "before the object is destroyed".  But it *will* run, except in certain cases that will kill the app pretty quickly anyway.  "Please improve your understanding on the topic"?  Show me one case where a finalizer won't run while the program is stable and not about to exit, and i'll let the condescension stand.

Comment: @Mike: The very point of a finalizer (that is, the `Finalize` method in VB, or the destructor in C#) is to clean up unmanaged resources held by an object before it's cleaned up itself.  `IDisposable` provides a way to do so sooner, in order to keep from tying up the unmanaged stuff longer than it has to.  But a correctly implemented `IDisposable` can go without being disposed, without major issues -- unless it's holding on to a resource that some other thread (or, in some cases, program) needs right now, the only real effect of forgetting to dispose is wasted resources til the finalizer runs.

Comment: @cHao: [This blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/04/26/don-t-blindly-count-on-a-finalizer.aspx) mentions four possible reasons why finalizers might not run. In my eyes, relying on finalizers to run is not a good idea, because it is not deterministic when and if they are called.

Comment: I found a couple of lines in the MSDN doco for Object.Finalize under the Remarks.
"Finalize method is used to perform cleanup operations on unmanaged resources held by the current object before the current object is destroyed." -- OK.
"This method is automatically called after an object becomes inaccessible..." -- by inaccessible do we mean it falls out of scope? (continued in next comment due to now many characters I get)

Comment: "Finalize operations have the following limitations: The exact time when the finalizer executes during garbage collection is undefined... not guaranteed to be released at any specific time, unless calling a Close method or a Dispose method." So calling Dispose causes Object.Finalize() to execute, freeing up unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Daniel: That blog post mentions 4 possible reasons, *all* of which mean, or will mean, the death of the app.  The only one that's kinda iffy is `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`, but it causes an OOM exception -- if the finalizer doesn't run, *the object won't be collected*.  Any object with a finalizer (which includes any IDisposable, whether it's disposed or not!) is stuck in memory while the thread's blocked, because the finalizer *must* run on it before it's released!  Only an app-killing event (OOM, killing the process, or unloading the AppDomain) will make that not the case.

Comment: @Mike: Generally, it's the other way around -- `Finalize` calls `Dispose`, which does the real work.  (In most cases, you can't directly call the finalizer...which is the major reason for `Dispose` in the first place.)  But yeah -- either way, `Dispose` and `Finalize` are supposed to do pretty much the same thing (release resources); it's just that `Dispose` runs under your control.  With `Finalize`, it's whenever the runtime feels like it.

Comment: @Daniel: And as for your other point, yeah -- it's good practice to dispose rather than waiting for a finalizer to run.  But it's not worth losing sleep over whether the caller will remember to dispose -- even if they don't, there's a mechanism designed to get the job done eventually.

Comment: @cHao: A lot of classes won't be cleaned up by finalizers--among them, any iterator which does a "yield return" within a synclock.  Since Microsoft includes explicit support for yield returns within synclocks, that would suggest that they're not horribly opposed to the idea of classes that must be Dispose'd to prevent bad things from happening.

Comment: @supercat: (1) Everything in every official mention of `IDisposable` and `Finalize` i've ever seen says users *must* be able to get by without disposing.  Show me different.  (2) In my tests, `yield return` within a `lock` block *doesn't* prevent collection.  (Though i had to jump through hoops just to lose a reference to one of these rogue locking iterators.  Maybe i did it wrong.)  Seems even locked objects get freed, unless you try to acquire locks in the finalizer as well.  That's a bad idea on its own -- and AFAIK it's *impossible anyway* with generators built by the compiler.

Comment: @cHao: (1) Microsoft may have had ambitions of a system where objects could always clean up after themselves if abandoned, but in practice making automatic cleanup actually work often requires adding a lot of complexity, and in some cases is essentially infeasible.  Suppose, for example, that one wishes to design a file-writer class which wraps a file class with some extra buffering.  Such a class must either wrap an unmanaged file class, or else must create a static reference to any finalizable file class it uses, to ensure that its finalizer will run before that of the file.

Comment: @cHao: Otherwise the file might get closed before the finalizer in the wrapper has a chance to write out its buffer.  Further, while closing files in a finalizer might be necessary, there's not really any guarantee that the finalizer thread won't be blocked for an arbitrary length of time by a "Read error on drive C--Retry or fail" dialog.  (2) Where was the lock object stored, and what thread was trying to access it?  A lock acquired in an iterator running on thread 1 and abandoned don't block thread 1, but will block other threads that try to acquire it.

Comment: @supercat: (1) The rules for `Finalize` are clear. It should only clean up resources the object directly controls, it should do so quickly once called, and it should not throw exceptions.  It sure as hell shouldn't be throwing up an error dialog.  Also, `Finalize` is about stability, not convenience.  If your file-writer was abandoned, the runtime doesn't care that it hasn't written its last bit of data yet.  *Nor should it.*  `Finalize` will always release the resources (unless the app dies off first), but it won't always release them when and how you like.  *That* is what `Dispose` is for.

Comment: @supercat: (2) I'd argue that `lock(...) { yield return... }` is evil anyway, precisely because you can't guarantee that the generator will even be *used* again within the next 10 years, much less be disposed.  You're letting some random schmoe's code control the lifetime of your lock (usually without even knowing it!), and that's going to cause some issues.  (BTW, support for locking in a generator isn't so much "explicit" as it is a side effect of support for `try`/`finally`, which is what a `lock` block breaks down to.)

Comment: @cHao: Sometimes maintaining system stability requires doing things which aren't possible--at least not safely--in a finalizer.  The runtime might not care whether the last bit of data was written to the file, but other code (possibly on another machine) which uses the file might have severe problems if the file gets closed with partially-written data.  A database system might armor itself against power loss by examining the database on the next start-up and finishing any partially-written commits and performing any necessary rollbacks, but it might not be able to do such things while "live".

Comment: @cHao: Fundamentally, whether or not objects should have Finalize methods, one should never write code that relies on them to do so unless one has particular knowledge of the Finalize behavior of the classes in question.  It's unfortunate that some language limitations make it difficult to maintain "Dispose correctness" in .net; if I were in charge of .net 5.0, that's one of the things I'd fix (e.g. by allowing a class to designate a method which will be called if a constructor throws; such a class would of course have to be prepared to deal with a partially-constructed object).

Comment: @supercat: I should rephrase. By "stability" i mean the stability of the runtime and the running OS. Neither one cares about your database, nor should it. If your code needs to guarantee a file was written, it should do so under its control, on its own watch. That is, `Dispose`. Code that doesn't should break gleefully, and be like "< *shrug* > you're the one who didn't close the file". `Dispose` is a good thing, *when implemented correctly*. Which includes accounting for its not being called. If an object can't do that, it needs a redesign anyway, cause it's not an Object.

Comment: @supercat: Let's go the other way with this for a second.  Say i have a Widget class, and a List<Widget> of my in-use widgets.  (Widget is not disposable; it has nothing to clean up.) Then you make a RemoteWidget class that extends Widget, but it now has sockets and such, so it implements IDisposable. And you give one to me. It's mine now; you don't know exactly what i'm doing with it behind the scenes, so you can't dispose it without breaking everything. Should every line of my code that ever dropped a Widget now need to be rewritten to dispose it, even if i can't know what you've done?

Comment: @cHao: Whoever creates an object has a responsibility for seeing that it gets cleaned up, either handling such cleanup itself or ensuring that the object is given to something else that promises to clean it up.  Putting an object into a List would absolve one of cleanup responsibility if and only if the holder of that list promised to call Dispose on everything therein before abandoning it.  Otherwise the owner of an object retains responsibility for tracking its logical lifetime.  Even if a List in which the object is stored drops its reference, the owner of the object should still have one.

Comment: @cHao: There are certainly times when it is to have a class that explicitly promises to handle cleanup by itself if abandoned; it can in some cases greatly simplify code that would create an object or acquire ownership, and may in some cases make a class much more useful.  On the other hand, such a promise is only mandatory if one wishes too have a base-factory legitimately return disposable instances.  Otherwise, the decision whether or not to promise automatic clean-up is a balance between adding complexity to a class, or to the code that creates instances of it.

Comment: @supercat: Such a promise is not only mandatory in certain cases: it is *always* mandatory.  Otherwise, you're violating LSP.  If you can't keep that promise, then you're doing something seriously wrong and need to rethink your design.

Comment: @supercat: In my example, i now own the Widget.  It's been given to me to do as i see fit.  The caller might already be gone.  Only, my Widget is really a RemoteWidget.  The caller shouldn't dispose it, as it no longer controls the object's lifetime (which may well exceed the caller's).  I won't dispose it, as for all i know and care it's a Widget (which *can't* be disposed).  So i should be able to treat it as a Widget, and trust that if it needs cleanup, it has taken advantage of the mechanism provided for doing so.

Comment: @cHao: If RemoteWidget implements IDisposable and doesn't explicitly promise that it may be safely abandoned, then anyone who would be inclined to call "new RemoteWidget()" must either satisfy the contract for IDisposable consumers or else find or create some alternative class which does promise that it can be safely abandoned.  If all of the users of a particular class would be able to comply with the IDisposable contract, there's no point making the class monstrously more complicated to make a promise nobody requires.

Comment: @supercat: `Object` *itself* promises that it can be safely abandoned.  (If it didn't, GC would be useless.)  Every Object (including every subtype -- read: *everything*) is bound by that promise.  `IDisposable` doesn't negate that, and the contract doesn't require that it *ever* be called.  In fact, if you want to talk contracts, the docs on `IDisposable.Dispose` explicitly say: *objects that implement IDisposable must also implement a finalizer to handle freeing resources when Dispose is not called.*  If the `IDisposable` interface could have a `protected void Finalize()`, it would.

Comment: @cHao: "Object" promises that one can create an instance via "new Object()" and safely abandon it.  Derived types make no such promise (many types have no public parameterless constructor).  The LSP is predicated upon the idea that code that a derived type should behave like the base *in circumstances where it could be given to code expecting the base type*.  If RemoteWidget doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, the only way one will get created is by code which calls "new RemoteWidget(...)"; such code cannot reasonably be expecting a Widget, so the LSP doesn't apply.

Comment: @supercat: On the contrary...the LSP most definitely applies.  I have no way (or right, for that matter) to know how an object outside my own code was created.  There's no condition that "if it was created using a default constructor" or "if i say new RemoteWidget() vs new Widget()" or any other such nonsense.  If B is a subclass of A, *regardless of how an A or B is created*, then by the definition of inheritance, a B *is* an A -- and i should be able to treat it like an A *in all cases*.  Not just when it's convenient for B.

Comment: @cHao: Code which is specified to receive a Widget may assume that the Widget will be valid for the duration specified by its contract (generally until the collection is abandoned or is asked to remove the item; most collections contractually forbidden from persisting items beyond that), and that it doesn't have to worry about cleanup.  The code which creates a RemoteWidget isn't code that's specified to receive a widget--it's spec'ed to receive RemoteWidget--and it is required to avoid passing its RemoteWidget to any code which is contractually permitted to persist it.

Comment: @supercat: Umm, no. That RemoteWidget can be passed anywhere, at any time, and done any Widgety thing anyone likes with. There is *no requirement at all* that it be locked away from the outside world, or that it only live as long as the code that created it, or even that the creator (or the receiver) dispose it! **The object itself, and *only* the object itself, is ultimately responsible for cleanup. If it can not do that, then it** -- not the caller, not the runtime, not the OS -- **is broken.** Period. Calling `Dispose` is polite and encouraged, but if it's required, that is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not a bad idea. There are a lot examples in the .NET framework, that do this, e.g. [`SqlClient.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx).

However, you need to document that the user needs to dispose the object as soon as he is finished using it.

You would do it like this:

```
using(PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> theGroups = 
      searchers.SearchForGroupsMatching("some*"))
{
    foreach (GroupPrincipal group in theGroups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.DisplayName);
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: The caller disposes? If this is the case, then is the object created in the method pointing to the same unmanaged object?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: Apologies for my badly edited comment... Are the two PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> instances (in the SearchForObjects method and in Main) both pointers to the same unmanaged object? In the example, I'm not calling Dispose() anywhere.

Comment: They are both pointing to the same **managed** object and thus: Yes, they are both internally pointing to the same unmanaged object.

Comment: If it's a class, then yes, both "instances" are actually references, to the same object.  You don't need to dispose the object in your search function if you're returning it to the caller.  In fact, it'd probably cause trouble if you did.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and cHao. That's what I was missing.

Comment: Bit harsh Daniel. Like I am, cHao is probably going to go off and look some things up. No sense wasting a learning opportunity.

Comment: @Daniel: cHao's comment was much the same as yours regarding the two "instance" being the same object. And cHao was correct - it caused all sorts of problems when Main referred to an object that no longer existed!

Comment: @Mike: I deleted my comments that where a response to cHao's comment to my answer. I apologize for reading too fast - I confused "the search method" with the method that calls the search method. cHao IS correct - calling dispose inside the search function is a bad idea if you return the object that you just disposed.

Comment: I've been looking stuff up this whole time, just to make sure i wasn't talking out of my ass.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not *wrong* to return a type that implements `IDisposable`, but it's inconvenient.

If you know that your caller doesn't need anything over and above a few simple properties, then there's a lot to be said for creating and returning a proxy object - this can simplify the caller's code and guarantee that the unmanaged resources are disposed properly.

In your case, if you really only want the `DisplayName` property, then I'd definitely create a proxy object. Then you don't need to worry at all about the lifetime of the `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>`, and, more critically, any connections or whathaveyou that this object keeps open.

This also simplifies testing: you can mock / stub out the method call that returns the proxy quite easily, as the proxy object is yours.

However, if your caller's code will use methods that require the full `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` then a proxy will clearly not do.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the questions at the bottom of my post. The rest of the discussion so far has centred around object disposal. I actually want more properties than just DisplayName but your comment about only keeping the "full" object if I need its methods is really good. I also hadn't thought about stubbing / mocking issues. +1

Answer (score 1):

Returning an object that implements IDisposable is a pattern which is simultaneously icky, useful, and in some sense unavoidable.  Having a factory supply the newly-created item only as a return value creates the danger that an exception might be thrown after the object has performed operations requiring cleanup, but before it has been stored in a place that will still exist when the exception is caught.

A safer pattern would be to pass by reference a place for a factory to store the object being created.  Following that pattern, if the factory stores a reference to a new object after it has been constructed well enough to tolerate Dispose, but before it has done any operations requiring cleanup, code which calls the factory could call Dispose on the newly-created object if an exception gets thrown any time after that.

Indeed, I would consider the latter style of object construction to be vastly superior to the former except for two factors:

1. The "using" construct, which allows a nice clear syntax to automate cleanup code, wouldn't really work with that style of factory (one could kludge it, but not in a way that would allow "using" to clean up the partially-constructed object if the constructor throws).

   The normal way of calling a constructor directly gives the new instance to the calling code as a return value, which disappears if the constructor throws an exception.  Every object creation eventually boils down to a call to "new()", so the only way to completely avoid having a function return value be the only existing reference to an IDisposable is to not have a class expose any public constructors, and have all its private and protected constructors accept a reference parameter in which to smuggle out the new object instance.

Having functions returning the only extant references to newly-constructed instances of IDisposable isn't wonderful, but it's a pretty common pattern since--as yet--neither c# nor .net really offers anything better.

Answer (score 0):

The calling code should be written with a using block and that will ensure `Dispose` is called. IDisposable is *the* way to control when disposal of resources happen, so returning an object that implements IDisposable is a standard idiom.